# Get all users that currently view a file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm wondering whether it is possible to acquire all users that are currently viewing / editing a file (so the users you would usually see on the top right corner, next to the comments and share buttons.

I found the [`getViewers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getViewers()) function int he documentation but this is not really what I'm looking for as it returns

> an array of users with view or comment permission

and not just the users that are currently in the file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a list of people who are allowed to view the file, not the ones who are currently viewing it. What you want is currently not available.

Answer (score 0):

This feature from the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) doesn't exist yet, try filing a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).